# Let $H=\langle a\rangle$ if $(\cdot)$ is the group action of conjugation of $G$ in $H$ then find $a\cdot H$, $b\cdot H$ and $c\cdot H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-actions

Let $G = S_3$ and $a=(12)$, $b=(13)$ and $c=(23)$. Let $H=\langle a\rangle$ if $(\cdot)$ is the group action of conjugation of $G$ in $H$ then find $a\cdot H$, $b\cdot H$ and $c\cdot H$

**My attempt**

Let $\cdot : G\times H \rightarrow H$ sucht that $(g,h)\rightarrow g*h*g^{-1}$ the action of conjugation, then for $g=a=(12)$ we have:

$$a*h*a^{-1}=(12)\circ(12)\circ(21)=(12)$$

For $b\cdot H$ we have:

$$b*h*b^{-1}=(13)\circ(12)\circ(31)=(32)$$

For $c\cdot H$ we have:

$$c*h*c^{-1}=(23)\circ(12)\circ(32)=(13)$$

Then $a\cdot H= \{(12),(1)(2)(3)\}$, $b\cdot H= \{(32),(1)(2)(3)\}$, $c\cdot H= \{(13),(1)(2)(3)\}$

Is this correct?

Comment: $H$ has two elements, so... not quite.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The other element is the identity, so it would be necessary to perform the same procedure with the identity, correct?

Comment: It's not hard, but the point is that your assertion that $a\cdot H$ is equal to the singleton $\{(1,2)\}$, etc. is incorrect.

Comment: I think I've added what was missing. @ArturoMagidin

Comment: If that's how you are going to write the identity, why do you write $a$ as $(12)$ instead of $(12)(3)$?